# If we had three eyes, would our visual perspective be fourth dimensional?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, perception, vision, visualization

If one covers up one eye, then he loses depth perception (two dimensional perspective). When we uncover that eye, we can now see depth (three dimensional perspective). My question is if we had four eyes, would we be able to see from a four dimensional perspective?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

The world we observe with our five senses is three dimensional. Two independent measurements are enough to calculate the three dimensional position of everything, which is what our brain does with the input of two eyes.

More eyes would only over constrain the solution, and might help in low lighting or long distance estimates when the errors are large.

Comment: Thanks. Would more eyes affect us in any regard/situation other than in low lighting or long distance estimates?

Comment: Everywhere where there were large visual errors for some reason, as for example side viewing. Many insects have in effect many eye, as their eyes are faceted. That is because they are in danger from a lot of predators and have to make fast decisions where to move to. Overconstrained solutions minimize errors.

Answer (score 5):

Your eyes are really just recording a flat image focused on your retina--it is your brain that extrapolates distance by comparing two images. In a way, you only see in two dimensions.

If you had a third eye, you might have better depth perception (if you had enough brain function to process that much data).

Comment: Thanks. I selected Anna's post as the answer because she posted first, but your answer was just as informative and helpful so I +1'd it.

Answer (score -1):

Umm...not really. You would need six eyes to see in 4-D. The reason for this is that our point of view is one dimension less than our current dimension. Therefore, to see in 4-D, you need to have a spherical view and maybe even spheric tesseract shaped eyes. (A tesseract is one dimension higher than a cube.) Also, our universe is still only 3-D anyway because you can't go earlyward or lateward without a wormhole, while the 4th dimension is time.

Answer (score -7):

yes .we can see the fourth dimension of 4d objects with a third eye.And we can only see the 4th dimensions of   objects that are 4d with third eye.
but unfortunately we , humans are 3d objects who can see maximum up to the 3 rd dimension of our world which is in a 4d universe!
[image: thsi is the 3 dimensions of our world]

Comment: This is nonsense.